# Imported the uuid library and tried to log it out using command, but it shows:TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: javascript, command

I ran the code using command prompt and it reported: "string is not a function".

here is my code:

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
const myaddress = uuid().split('-').join('');
console.log(myaddress)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid then you likely need to specify what part of the API (or version) you are wanting to use. So using version 4 would look something like this:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const myaddress = uuidv4().split('-').join('');
// output might look like "00207ec4afeb4e2ebed0fb9d9d0a5ef2"
```

https://npm.runkit.com/uuid is a simple online tool to test the code.

Comment: ok, Thank you so much, I used the exact lines of codes you stated and it worked. So does that I would replace v4 with v1 if I am to use version 1?

Comment: Correct @ValentineIfeanyi, simply replace `v4` with `v1` to use version 1. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) lists all the different versions and usage.

Comment: thank you so much Patrick, I am grateful.